# Wrapping middleware as a function declaration

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

How do I structure middleware to pass it to a route handler without immediately invoking it?

```
// Changing this
import auth from '../middleware/auth'

userRouter.get('/dashboard', auth().authenticate(), function(req, res) {
  res.send('It worked! User id is: ' + req.user.id)
})

// To this
import auth from '../middleware/auth'

userRouter.get('/dashboard', auth.authenticate, function(req, res) {
  res.send('It worked! User id is: ' + req.user.id)
})
```

Middleware function

`middleware/auth.js`

```
module.exports = function() {
  var strategy = new JwtStrategy(options, function(payload, done) {
    (...)
  });
  (...)
  return {
    initialize: () => {
      return passport.initialize();
    },
    authenticate: () => {
      return passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false });
    }
  };
};
```

I suppose I must pass `req, res, next` to `authenticate`, but then how do I pass it to `passport.authenticate`?

Answer (score 0):

Half, poor man solution. Doesn't allow extra handling.

```
module.exports = function() {
  var strategy = new JwtStrategy(options, function(payload, done) {
    (...)
  });
  (...)
  return {
    initialize: () => {
      return passport.initialize();
    },
  authenticate: passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false })
};
```